# Management of SharePoint List fields

Tags: list, permissions

I've received the below requirements from a user to build a SP list/infopath for managing sensitive information submitted by users, I know the majority of the below is possible my question is can specific fields in the list e.g the answer field be completely blocked for editing to specific groups of users in both the SP list and Infopath.

### **Requestor Role (Raise a Question)**

1. **Submit request**

Select one/many of four specific teams to respond

Set question category and sub-category according to pre-defined taxonomy

Set other customized fields (ID of other related question etc)

Receive notification when question has been answered or further info requested.

2. **Edit request**

Edit submitted request to enhance information provided / add additional context

Only fields that were editable during submission can be updated

Information provided by responder teams in response fields cannot be edited

3. **Resubmit request**

Resubmit to responder teams if request has been edited or response is insufficient

### Responder Role (Provide Response)

1. Receive notification that new question raised
2. Respond to question (in field that is not editable by the requestor)
3. Edit fields set by the requestor (reassign to other teams etc)
4. Request further information from requestor

### Observer Role (Browse questions & responses)

1. Search previous questions and answers
2. Fields are not editable by the observer